# How do you loop Readline statements?

Tags: c#

I have a homework assignment and I am stuck on a certain part of the question.
How do I loop numbers regarding the readline statement.

In other words, suppose I have two numbers that I want to input. Instead of typing out the readline statement twice, how do I get a loop that would allow me to type the readline statement once?

Comment: Have you asked your teacher for help?

Comment: Flow control statements are critical to learning programming.  This must have been covered in your book.

Answer (score 2):

> have two numbers that I want to input. Instead of typing out the readline statement twice, how do I get a loop that would allow me to type the readline statement once

Well, if you want two numbers, then you're going to need two variables (or an array), so I assume you're trying to change this:

```
int firstNumber;
int secondNumber;
firstNumber = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
secondNumber = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
```

into something like this:

```
int[] myNumbers = new int[2];

for(int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
{
    myNumbers[i] = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
}
```

but think about this:

- Will the prompt be the same for both numbers?  Or will the prompt change between inputs
- Is it easier to assess the variables independently versus a part of the array/list?
- Will having the numbers in a structure benefit other parts of my app (looping to get a sum, etc.)

I think a loop as fine so long as you don't end up with logic inside the lop that changes depending on which number you're using:

```
int[] myNumbers = new int[2];

for(int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
{
    if i == 0  //  bad
        string prompt = "Enter the first number";
    else
        string prompt = "Enter the second number";

    Console.WriteLine(prompt);
    myNumbers[i] = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much. Im having a really hard time understanding this part. Any good books that explain this further? Or even websites?

Comment: ***any book*** on C# will cover this.  This is basic intro-level stuff.  You got two good answers here already.... pick up a book and read.

Answer (score 1):

```
int[] myInputs = new int[2];

for(int i=0; i < 2; ++i)
{
    myInputs[i] = Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
}
```

After this, `myInputs[0]` is the first value, and `myInputs[1]` is the second value.

Comment: +1, myInputs.Lenght would be better though - I hate magic numbers in code

Comment: I would use Int32.TryParse instead of Int32.Parse

Comment: @Valid:  Yes, but then I have to explain what it means to `try` something.   This guy doesn't understand loops.  I'm not going to try to explain SEH to him.   One small step at a time.

Comment: His teacher might know ;)

Comment: So how am I supposed to ask the question without it being considered cheating? Obviously I want to learn c sharp since giving away the answer wont help me learn in the long run. How do I ask questions without it being considered cheating?

Comment: @user249240, you should post what you have tried to show you are really trying to learn